# VB.NET dictionary of multiple types

Tags: vb.net

I am very new to VB.NET, and I come from an Objective-C background.

In Objective-C, I could create an `NSMutableDictionary` which could hold *any* types of values.

Here with VB.NET, I managed to make a `Dictionary`, but when I initialized an instance of it, I am asked for a *specific value type*. How can I enable any value types within one single dictionary?

Comment: You need to save any kind of objects in the same dict ? i.e. Integer, String, MyClassI, MyClassII ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a dictionary to hold objects like this:

```
Dim myDictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
```

And then to supply it:

```
myDictionary.Add("keyA", New Button)
myDictionary.Add("keyB", "Test")
```

This is probably not considered best programming practice.  It's better to take advantage of generics and have a dictionary hold a common class or interface of items.

Having multiple dictionaries for each class or interface of items would be more efficient and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Object` type to hold any value. Example:

```
Dim myDict as New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()
```