# DateTime as Object in dictionary

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270627/vb-net-dictionary-of-multiple-types#9270687) that a dictionary (of string, object) can hold multiple variable types. However, in the function below, endTime does not appear to get assigned. The line `Console.Write(lobjWaveOutList(0)("endTime"))` in the code below gives me the error 'the given key was not present in the dictionary'.

```
Private lobjWaveOutList As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))()
Public Sub addIndex(waveOut As Object, endTime As DateTime)
    Console.WriteLine("endTime:")
    Console.WriteLine(endTime)
    lobjWaveOutList.Add(New Dictionary(Of String, Object)() From {{"waveOut", waveOut}})
    lobjWaveOutList.Add(New Dictionary(Of String, Object)() From {{"endTime", endTime}})
    Console.Write(lobjWaveOutList(0)("endTime"))
End Sub
```

I called the addIndex function with the following parameters:

```
waveouts.addIndex(New WaveOut(), DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10))
```

Comment: Why do you have list of dictionaries? Sounds like this is where the problem lies. Please elaborate why you can't survive on just one dictionary.

Comment: Well, Console.Write(lobjWaveOutList(0)("waveOut")) works fine. I use it as a multidimensional associative array of sorts. Each dictionary in lobjWaveOutList holds info for a seperate waveOut object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lobjWaveOutList(0)("endTime")` will not work because it is accessing the *first* dictionary in the list, which only contains a `"waveOut"` item.  The `"endTime"` item is in the *second* dictionary in the list.  To get that one, you'd need to do this:

```
 Console.Write(lobjWaveOutList(1)("endTime"))
```

As Neolisk pointed out, it would seem more appropriate, based on your example, to simply have a single dictionary, containing multiple items, rather than a list of dictionaries, each only containing a single item.

Comment: Seems like I misinterpreted the dictionary object, there is indeed no need for me to have a list of dictionaries. Thank you and Neolisk for showing me that.

Comment: +1. @NotABlueWhale: If anything, you could use `Dictionary(Of String, List(Of Object))`.

Answer (score 0):

As you have a list of Dictonary "endtime" is here: `lobjWaveOutList(1)("endTime")`